# How to get complete HTML body using browser helper object (BHO) in case of DHTML/AJAX page?

Tags: c++, ajax, dhtml, atl, bho

I'm writing a BHO that analyze the HTML taken from the `'onDocumentComplete'` event of `'DWebBrowserEvents2'`. Currently it works fine, unless I have a `DHTML/AJAX` page, where HTML handle is delivered too soon.

For sample, I tried using it on `'http://www.google.com'`. From the `'onDocumentComplete'` event I can get most of the page but in the topmost link/anchors, the `'href'`  for maps, videos, orkut etc. is not available (normally it is **`javascript:void(0)`**).

Has anyone any ideas how to capture it when the page is fully loaded rather than just when the frame/body is loaded?

Thanks,

**UPDATE**

It seems there is some problem with the MSHTML API. I have posted the same question on MSDN forum and some response. Also I have detailed out my problem and findings....

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ieextensiondevelopment/thread/d517dbd1-df22-4dce-8ff9-0ca6786757f9

In case someone finds some way to solve this then please do share...

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AJAX DHTML changes mostly don't cause a further `onDocumentComplete` call.

You need to register for further Window or Document events such as `DISPID_HTMLWINDOWEVENTS2_ONLOAD`.

One method is to advise the window of a com object that you provide with the generic event sink interface.
`hr = AtlAdvise(winDisp, pWinHandler, DIID_HTMLWindowEvents2, &dwCookie);`

When this further event is triggered re examining the document you will find that it is updated.